# Remove an element from linked list at certain position

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have done so far this progress by creating a function in which i am 
passing position of node which i want to get deleted

```
    void remove(int pos)
    {
        node *temp=new node();
        current=head->getnext();
        for(int i=1;i<=pos;i++)
        {
            if(i=(pos-1))
            {
                temp=current->getnext(); 
                current->setnext(current->getnext()->getnext());
                delete temp;

            }
            current=current->getnext();
        }
        elenum--;
    }
```

Comment: This code has at least 2 bugs that should be fixed before it will be even remotely ready for review...

Answer (score 2):

## Boundary checks

You never verify if `pos` is actually a valid position in the list.

## `nullptr` checks

You never check if any call to `getnext()` returns a `nullptr`.

Without one kind of check, your code will very likely try to dereference a `nullptr` if `pos` is greater than the number of elements in the list.

## Wrong condition

`if(i=(pos-1))` sets  `i` to `pos-1`, and if unequal to `0`, executes the branch, deleting a wrong node from the list (it's only the right node if `pos == 2`). You probably meant to write `if(i == (pos - 1))`.

## Memory leak

At the begin of the function, you allocate a new node. This node will never be deleted (it either crashes because of nullptr dereference, or another node pointer gets assigned to `temp` before `temp` gets deleted.

## Unnecessary nesting

The `if` check inside the `for` loop isn't necessary: Just run the `for` loop until `i < pos - 1` (`i == (pos - 1)` will then be true after the loop ends).

> Fixed code:

```
void remove(int pos) {
    if(pos > elenum) return;

    auto current = head->getnext();
    for(int i = 1; current != nullptr && i < (pos-1); ++i) {
        current = current->getnext();
    }

    if(current == nullptr || current->getnext() == nullptr) return;

    auto temp = current->getnext();
    current->setnext(temp->getnext());
    delete temp;

    --elenum;
}
```

## Further reading

I suggest you look for learning material about `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`, as those will simplify memory management quite a lot (if used correctly).